# android-support-v4.jar isn't importing correctly in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, jar, compatibility, android-support-library

I'm trying to get an app to compile that uses the `android-support-v4.jar` and the `Fragmentation` classes it contains, but I keep getting messages whenever I try to compile that there are errors in the code.  All of the errors have to do with different `Fragmentation` classes that are in the `.JAR`.  I have tried `ctrl-clicking` the project folder and then selecting `Android Tools -> Add Compatibility Library` and I keep getting this error:

```
[2011-12-20 11:55:31 - Android Compatibility JAR not found:]
/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/v4/android-support-v4.jar
```

Why would it be looking for the `.JAR` in Eclipse's Package Contents?  I've gone into the project properties and went to the Java Build Path, and imported the `.JAR` from the `MainActivity/libs` folder, that didn't work, and then I tried to import it from my SDK directory, and that didn't work.  I've fixed the project properties and cleaned and built it countless times, I've restarted Eclipse, my computer, re-downloaded and installed Eclipse, the Android SDK's and ADT and still nothing.  I am completely stumped.

---

### Edit

---

I've gone through the build path and imported the .JAR from both the `MainActivity/libs` and my SDK directory.  For the hell of it I added the .JAR in the directory that keeps appearing in the errors and that hasn't worked.  What's making Eclipse look for it in it's Application Package Contents?

---

### Update

---

So after tinkering the project contents aren't showing any errors but the MainActivity folder still says that there is one and I still can't compile.

Like nyah:

[image]

---

### Revision

---

So I think the question may be "Why is Eclipse looking for the .JAR in the Eclipse Application's package contents instead of the `libs` directory of the project or the Android SDK directory that I used to import it as an external .JAR?"

---

### Update #2

---

I am only getting one error now after tinkering, it's on this method:

```
@Override
public MenuItem setOnActionExpandListener(OnActionExpandListener onActionExpandListener) {
    // Noop
    return this;
}
```

The Quick Fix says that I should delete the @Override annotation but that method must override a super class method.

These are the errors that it shows:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The method setOnActionExpandListener(MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener) of type SimpleMenuItem must override a superclass method
- implements android.view.MenuItem.setOnActionExpandListener
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that my Debug Certificate had expired so I just needed to delete `~/.android/debug.keystore` and restart Eclipse and everything worked.

Answer (score 19):

Looks like it is looking for jar here :/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/v4/android-support-v4.jar

android-support-v4.jar is found in <sdk>/extras/android/compatibility/v4

Please make sure you add this as an external jar in the java build path

Comment: Yeah I did, I thought I had mentioned that, I'll add it in.  Like I said I've added the .JAR from the MainActivity/libs and as an external .JAR from my SDK directory and that hasn't done anything that I can see.

Comment: Is that path still valid? When I added it as a dependancy in Gradle, it ended up here: <sdk>/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4

Answer (score 12):

I could solve this problem by
1- delete "android-support-v4.jar" from lib
2- right click on the name of the project choose "Android Tools" and "Add Support Library"

Answer (score 4):

If this is still not solved:
Like already said, in Eclipse go to your Project Properties > Java Build Path > Libs > Add External and get the one from the adk directory.

Also set up Java 1.6 as your default compile version if you already haven't. This should solve the Override Errors you described.

Comment: Hi Juke, welcome to stackoverflow and thanks for the answer provided!

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, the problem is still not solved.  I've already made sure the build path points to the external JAR in my SDK directory and that Eclipse uses 1.6 to compile.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried the hard way by setting up a fresh Eclipse installation? Saves you more time and nerves than arguing with this error for so long.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this question has been answered, but this is a known issue that is supposed to be fixed in the ADT-17 plugin release according to comment 9 here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21488

In addition, people who have this problem can copy the compatibility JAR to the location it says it can't find it.  Clearly it's looking in the wrong place (since it's checking the Eclipse directory rather than the android-sdk directory), so the simple fix, for now, is simply to put the package where it wants to find it, even though it doesn't belong.

For me it was as simple as copying the v4 directory within C:/android-sdk/extras/android/support/ into the C:/eclipse/ directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem running in Ubuntu. Go to Tools->Options.
Check Force https://... to http://
Open Android SDK Manager. Check Extras->Android Support Library.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me. At the top of MainActivity.java I had the next imports giving errors:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

In each of the lines on the left they had the light bulb making some suggestions. If you click on it, one of the options will be "Fix project setup". You then will be able to choose between several options for fixing the imports, you should choose the one that specifies the android-support-v4.jar.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on ur project --> select android tools --> select add support library and simply installed  the supporting libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try not to do Android Tools -> Add Compatibility Library, and only add the jar in java build path library?.

I use this jar library of this way and it works without any problem.

Comment: I did, and my coworker has this working fine on his machine, I'm really stumped about this

Comment: For me, it's when I use Android Tools > Add Compatibility Library that it looks in the Eclipse folder. I'm not sure why, seems silly.

Answer (score 0):

Another caveat was running Android SDK Manager in Windows 7 without administrator privileges. It would try to install support package, but would always fail, and the actual package never got downloaded to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v4\android-support-v4.jar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Under the project properties:Java Build Path:Order and Export tab, the box next to android-support-v4.jar wasn't checked. I checked the box, and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Make sure that you enter the same API for "Target SDK" and "Compile with" during Android project creation (or in the Manifest file once created).