# FragmentTransaction in support-v4 does not have detach()?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've been looking far and wide for solutions to this but alas in my sample project I still get the following errors

"The method isDetached() is undefined for the type Fragment"

"The method detach(Fragment) is undefined for the type FragmentTransaction"

What is the matter here? I have the following imports

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;
```

And I use SDK version 8

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Comment: did you import the V4 support package android-support-v4.jar to your SDK. Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579915/android-support-v4-jar-isnt-importing-correctly-in-eclipse

Comment: Yup :)
http://i.imgur.com/i1p9l.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the jar file you're importing is the most recent one. There are a few android-support-v4.jar files and I've caught a few differences in the APIs they implement.

Download it again and make sure that you import the most recent file in eclipse.